# Remove Blur or unmask an image

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, pytorch

I am using MTCNN to detect face in an image, FACENET to extract and save features from each detected face and OpenCV Gaussian Blur filter to mask the detected faces.

[image: Original Image]

[image: Masked Image]

[image: Target Face]

```
    def face_and_features(img):
    boxes, _ = mtcnn.detect(img)
    print(boxes)

    for i, box in enumerate(boxes):
        a,b,c,d = box
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = int(a), int(b), int(c), int(d)
        face = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        cv2.imwrite(f"face{i}.jpg",face)
        
        face = cv2.resize(face, (160, 160))
        face = face.transpose((2, 0, 1))
        face = torch.from_numpy(face).float()
        face = face.unsqueeze(0)

        features = facenet(face)

        filename = "face_{}.npy".format(i)
        np.save(filename, features.detach().numpy())
        with open("bounding_boxes.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write("{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {} \n".format(x1, y1, x2, y2, filename, datetime.datetime.now(), frame_number))
    return features
       
def masking(img):
    filename = "bounding_boxes.txt"
    masked_img = img.copy()
    with open(filename,'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            x,y,w,h,f_name,time, f_no = line.split(",")
            x,y,w,h = int(x), int(y), int(w), int(h)
            roi_color = masked_img[y:h, x:w]
            masked_img[y:h, x:w] = cv2.GaussianBlur(roi_color, (51,51), 0)
    return masked_img, f_name, time, f_no
```

My end goal is to find the target face in the masked image by comparing saved facial features(or any other method) and unmask target face only. Any idea or advice ?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to compare the features of target image in masked image and unmask the face once there is feature match as whole process is done on real time video at time .

Comment: undeclared crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/remove-blur-or-mask-from-image/11812

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically detecting faces using MTCNN, extracting features from each face using FACENET and saving them, then blurring the faces in the image using OpenCV Gaussian Blur filter.

To find the target face in the masked image, you can compare the saved features with the features extracted from the target face. You can use cosine similarity to calculate the similarity between the saved features and the target face features. The face with the highest similarity score will be the target face.

In the masking function, you can add a step to unmask the target face by replacing the blurred area with the original face region.

Here's a sample code that implements the steps I mentioned above:

```
def compare_features(target_face, saved_features):
    target_face = cv2.resize(target_face, (160, 160))
    target_face = target_face.transpose((2, 0, 1))
    target_face = torch.from_numpy(target_face).float()
    target_face = target_face.unsqueeze(0)

    target_features = facenet(target_face)
    similarity_scores = []
    for i, feature in enumerate(saved_features):
        score = cosine_similarity(target_features, feature)
        similarity_scores.append((i, score))
    return max(similarity_scores, key=lambda x: x[1])

def unmask_target_face(img, target_index, x, y, w, h):
    target_face = img[y:h, x:w]
    masked_img = img.copy()
    masked_img[y:h, x:w] = target_face
    return masked_img

def find_target_face(img, saved_features):
    target_face, target_coords = detect_target_face(img)
    target_index, score = compare_features(target_face, saved_features)
    x, y, w, h = target_coords[0], target_coords[1], target_coords[2], target_coords[3]
    unmasked_img = unmask_target_face(img, target_index, x, y, w, h)
    return unmasked_img

saved_features = [np.load(f"face_{i}.npy") for i in range(len(boxes))]
masked_img, _, _, _ = masking(img)
unmasked_img = find_target_face(masked_img, saved_features)
```

Comment: Cosine Similarity is giving multiple 1's as result value as input to detect_target_face is masked image hence not many facial features.

Comment: Consider using Euclidean distance instead of cosine similarity. You can compare the Euclidean distance between the extracted features of the masked image and saved features of each detected face. The face with the smallest Euclidean distance is likely the target face. Additionally, consider adjusting the parameters of the Gaussian Blur filter to produce a smaller blur effect that still conceals the face.

Comment: It seems like features detected by FaceNet for the face in the full image and a cropped face are different.

Comment: Yes, this is because FaceNet is a deep neural network trained on a large dataset of faces, and it expects the input image to be standardized, i.e. have a certain size, aspect ratio, etc. When you crop a face from the full image, you potentially lose information that FaceNet uses to extract features, such as the relative position of the face within the image, the background, etc. To overcome this issue, consider resizing the cropped face to the same size as the input image that FaceNet was trained on, before passing it through the network.

Comment: As you can see in code above the cropped face is already resized to standard 160*160 input image size for FaceNet.

Comment: Then the issue might be with the MTCNN face detection box coordinates. MTCNN might be detecting faces inaccurately, or the box coordinates might not be the same as the FaceNet input size. Try printing the face shapes before and after resizing, and check if the face shape is correct and matches the FaceNet input size. You can also visualize the MTCNN detection boxes to see if they are covering the entire face.

Comment: Also while unmasking as we only have masked image, how to remove the blur from target face in the masked image.